# How to handle form submit request using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, http-status-code-405

When submitting the form the page is refreshed and shows an error code 405.
submitForm method in the javascript handless the submit button click event.
Although the data is going to the backend and working fine, but something is breaking in the frontend I am unable to figure it out need help...!

---

**error response on browser**

[image]

---

**Html form**

```
<form method="post" id="formBulkOrder" action="">
            <div class="row offset-top-4">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="boDeliveryLocation">Select delivery location</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="boDeliveryLocation" id="boDeliveryLocation" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="boAvailableQuantity">Available Quantity</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="boAvailableQuantity" id="boAvailableQuantity" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="boOrderQuantity">Order Quantity Quantity</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="boOrderQuantity" id="boOrderQuantity" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" offset-top-1 text-center">
                <button type="submit" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

---

**javascript code**

```
window.orderingModule = {};

let BulkUpdate = ((manager) => {
    let availableQuantity = undefined;
    let itemId = undefined;
    let itemName = undefined;
    let init = async () => {
        await cacheDom();
        await biendEvent();
        await renderSelectItemDropdown();
    }

    let cacheDom = async () => {
        fetchAvailableQuantitybutton = await document.getElementById("btnToFetchItemAvailabelQuantity");
        //formSubmitButton = await document.getElementById("btnSearch");
        orderPlaceDiv = await document.getElementById("hide");
        availableQuantityInput = await document.getElementById("boAvailableQuantity");
        inputQunatityInput = await document.getElementById("boOrderQuantity");
        form = document.querySelector("#formBulkOrder");
        
    }
    //let is not working
    var renderDeliveryLocation = () => {

        $("#hide").show();
        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#boDeliveryLocation").kendoComboBox({
                placeholder: "Select",
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                filter: "startswith",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/BulkUpdate/GetDeliveryLocations"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
    let renderBulkOrderForm = () => {
        renderDeliveryLocation()
        setAvailableQuanityInput()

    }
    //let is not working
    var setAvailableQuanityInput = () => {
        availableQuantityInput.setAttribute('value', availableQuantity);
        
       

    }
    let renderSelectItemDropdown = () => {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#comboBox").kendoComboBox({
                placeholder: "Select",
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                filter: "startswith",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/BulkUpdate/GetAllItemId"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

    let biendEvent = async () => {
        await fetchAvailableQuantitybutton.addEventListener("click", fetchAvailableQuanity)
        //await formSubmitButton.addEventListener("click", submitForm)
        form.addEventListener("submit", submitForm);
    }
    let submitForm = (event) => {
        //event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
        console.log(event.target)
        console.log(event.target.elements)
        console.log(event.target.boDeliveryLocation.value)
        console.log(event.target.elements.boOrderQuantity.value)
        

        console.log("inside sublit form")

        let data = {
            itemId: itemId,
            DeliveryLocationId: event.target.boDeliveryLocation.value,
            orderedQuantity: event.target.boOrderQuantity.value,
            
        }
        console.log(data)
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('itemId', itemId)
        formData.append('DeliveryLocationId', event.target.boDeliveryLocation.value)
        formData.append('orderedQuantity', event.target.boOrderQuantity.value)
        formData.append('PartName', itemName);
        console.log(formData)
        fetch('/BulkUpdate/PlaceBulkOrder', {
            method: "POST",
            //body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            //body: data,
            body: formData,
            //headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.json);
                response.json()
            })
            .then(json => console.log(json))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        

        
    }
    
    let fetchAvailableQuanity = async () => {
        nameComboBox = await $("#comboBox");
        
        itemName = nameComboBox.data('kendoComboBox').text().split("-")[1].trim();
        itemId = nameComboBox.data('kendoComboBox').value();

        console.log(itemName, itemId);

        var data = {
            itemId: parseInt(itemId),
        }
        await console.log(data);

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('itemId', itemId)

        await console.log(formData);

        await fetch('/BulkUpdate/GetAvalilableQuantityOfItem', {
            method: "POST",
            //body: JSON.stringify(data),
            //body: data,
            body: formData,
            //headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);
                availableQuantity = json;
                renderBulkOrderForm();
                
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    manager.onDocumentReady = () => {
        console.log("ready");
        $("#hide").hide();
        init()
    }
    return { 'initialize': init}

})(window.orderingModule)
//})(window)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can observe, you are programatically submitting the form using JavaScript which is triggered when you click the Search button. But, the problem is the HTML form submit is also triggered by the same submit action and since, the Action is an empty string as represented in your HTML code, you are getting the Error Code 405. To fix this issue, after executing the fetch, return false. You can get more information from your network tab in your browser.